# Apple touch icon for SharePoint site not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, master-page, apple-ios

Tried creating an apple touch icon for my SP team site, below is the link tag in the header tag of the master page as suggested on the apple support portals and other SharePoint portals.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../../SiteAssets/images/appl_icon.png" />
```

Some suggested, that the size of the image should be exact with respect to model and I was trying to get the icon on a 6S Plus model, so resized the image to 180x180 as well. But still the icon I provided doesn't appear but a snapshot of the over all site appears as the touch icon.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain the image location will resolve? I'd normally have my icon stored in my SP site and refer to its location using SPUrl~SiteCollection like:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/Custom/Styles/Images/apple-touch-icon.png%>" runat="server" />
```